# Menu bar clock differs from system time

Tags: macos, menu-bar

I have a problem with the menu bar clock showing the wrong time after resuming from sleep. This doesn't happen a lot but when it does, I have to restart to fix it.

I have checked that my timezone is still correct (Eastern), the time shown in the Date & Time app is right and time syncs with apple servers - shown in the screenshot below.

Why is this happening? How can I fix the menu bar clock without restarting?

MacOS Mojave v10.14.5 (18F132)

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What is the version of macOS that you are running?

Comment: If you are not on the latest public release of your version of macOS, updating it would be advisable, as this could be due to a bug in macOS.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked about a fix without restarting, but I really think your best option is to reset the NVRAM which, of course, requires you to restart your Mac. The reason for this is that your Mac's Non-Volatile RAM stores its timezone information.

**Reset your NVRAM**

To reset the NVRAM you'll need to follow these steps:

1. **Fully shut down your Mac**
2. **Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.** You have to make sure you press these keys before the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** for about 20 seconds (or until you know for sure your Mac has rebooted a second time)
4. Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.

Comment: “How can I fix the menu bar clock without restarting?”

Comment: @samh Thanks for the feedback - I've added a couple of sentences at the beginning of my answer to address *why* I'm suggesting this, despite having to do a restart.  If resetting the NVRAM works, then the problem won’t reappear and they won’t need to worry about it again, restarting or otherwise.

Comment: Didn't work for me.