# Mac chooses wrong date/time which is 7 hours ahead of the timezone chosen

Tags: time, timezone

I have chosen to set date/time automatically based on location:

[image]

The time now is 2:28 PM but Mac shows it as 9:29 PM:

[image]

On Terminal app, `date` command shows the correct time:

```
date
Sun May 31 14:29:26 PDT 2020
```

However, Mail, Calendar, Outlook etc., all show the wrong date which is 7 hours ahead.  How can I fix this problem?  The menu bar shows the wrong time as well:

[image]

I tried [resetting NVRAM](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/365416/220595) but that didn't help.

Comment: That's weird, it looks like it can detect the location but didn't set the time zone for some reason, when it does, it looks something like [this](https://media.kumowoon1025.com/images/macos-timezone-sntp.png)

Comment: Does the same error occur in Safe Mode: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262? Does the same error occur in a newly-created user account?

Comment: Your system time seems to be accurate (but you can run `sudo sntp $(cut -d' ' -f 2 /etc/ntp.conf)` to check). Did you try to change the region to something else, reboot and then change it back?

Comment: Could you please run `TZ=C date`?  This should show the date in UTC (without any timezone).

Answer (score 1):

Check in System Preferences → Region & languages to see if "Region" is set correctly.

---

When the device has wrong date/ time, the location will also not get updated. (I don't know the correct reason, I've just seen this a few times.)

So the time will also be wrong since correct location has not been determined.

So to break the loop, you need to enter correct time at least once. Then verify that you can connect to internet in Safari and then set date/ time to auto.

Comment: System time gets set via NTP which seems to work correctly (as Terminal shows the correct time).

Comment: that's new to me.. however I've experienced this 3-4 times whenever Mac shuts down due to low battery & each time I had to do what I wrote in the answer.

Comment: We are talking about two different problems: HTTPS doesnt' connect if the time difference is too big (which impacts browsing), NTP may not update (or take a long time to incrementally catch up) the time if the difference is too big. Setting the time manually fixes both problems of course. But OP seems to have the correct time in Terminal so NTP most probably works ok.